# Quest Benchmark Factory and TPC-H: analyzing performance?

Tags: benchmarking, olap

Is it possible to generate a Transaction per second vs Used Load with Quest Benchmark Factory for TPC-H benchmark? Would this measurement be a good indication of performance for OLAP workloads?

[working with Oracle 11g RAC database with RAID storage]